# Export path for play 2.1.1 on terminal whenever opening a new terminal

Tags: playframework-2.0

I installed the `play2.1.1` as the website says(http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/Installing). 
I can successfully do things in terminal like: `$play` help   play new `my5app`

However, as long as I open a new terminal, the `play` command doesn't work in the new terminal, I have to do the `export PATH=$PATH:/Users/xxx/Applications/play-2.1.1` on it again.

Is this normal or I did some procedure wrong the first time I install `PLAY2.1.1`?

Comment: This is normal, you'll need to add it to your ~/.bashrc.

Comment: If you are on *nix system, you should take a look at pvm : https://github.com/kaiinkinen/pvm

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a `symlink` in your `/usr/bin` folder (with `sudo`) to concrete Play version(s) it's useful, when you are gonna to use different versions of Play (btw it doesn't need be placed in Application folder, as it's not an application, so you better move it to other one - for an example - `~/play-src/2.1.1/`, then create just the symlnik to `play` script in required folder

```
cd /usr/bin
sudo ln -s ~/play-src/2.0.4/play play204
sudo ln -s ~/play-src/2.1.1/play play211
```

In this approach you can easily choose which Play version you want to use at the moment, just by writing:

```
play211 new new-app-ver-2-1-1
```