# Dual play frameworks on the same system

Tags: java, playframework

I have installed play 2.0.4 in my windows Xp and want to use play 2.1.0 in the same system. What configuration changes should I make so that I can run a java project in play 2.1.0.

Comment: Do you want to run both `2.0.4` and `2.1.0` on the same system or do you want to upgrade your current version to `2.1.0`? If the latter, take a look at the [migration guide](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/Migration).

Comment: For development or as servers ?

Comment: Aerus-I want to run both 2.0.4 and 2.1.0 on the same system

Comment: nico_ekito- For development but I am just a novice as of now

Answer (score 1):

There is [answer for similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16255867/1066240) dedicated for mac/unix.

In Win you can [create symlinks](https://superuser.com/a/117177/129014) pointing to the proper version of Play directly in the instance folder

Comment: +1. And one tip, if your projects are already created, you can directly launch `sbt`, which will works with any 2.0+ versions.